# How can I configure my API to send an ID rather than a name via JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I am configuring a basic API in Ruby. It contains two simple tables and an associative, but my join table is giving me a problem that should be easy to solve. When I open my view in the browser, it shows the object `name` (in this case, `people`). However, in view.json it shows the `id`. I want the API to send the `name` as JSON and not the `id`. How can I do this? The configuration of my API is below:

```
json.array!(@leituras) do |leitura|
  json.extract! leitura, :id, :pessoa_id, :livro_id
  json.url leitura_url(leitura, format: :json)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try RABL https://github.com/nesquena/rabl. RABL implements a new template to render Json, xml, ... as a view. I'm using for my API and it's very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Active Model Serializers.

I wouldn't recommend RABL, you might end up with a bunch of n+1 queries, personally the DSL is a little weird.

Add a serializer for your object.

```
class LeituraSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, pessoa_id, :livro_id
end
```

And in your controller you can do

```
class LeiturasController < ApplicationController
  def show
     @leituras = Leitura.find(params[:id])

    render json: @leituras
  end
end
```

Read more Here : https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/README.md